# List all the MS SQL Server Objects ->LinkedServers->Providers using SQL

Tags: sql-server

How to List all MS SQL Server Providers List available using SQL.
like 
 Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
 Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
 SQLXMLOLEDB.4.0
 SQLXMLOLEDB
 SQLOLEDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executing the stored procedure `sp_MSset_oledb_prop` without parameters will return a table of the available providers and their options:

```
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop
```

Answer (score 1):

This will list the OLEDB providers showing the following: Provider Name, Parse Name, and Provider Description.

```
EXEC xp_enum_oledb_providers
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access it using code, try this (which is contained within the other procedure):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#providers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #providers;
CREATE TABLE #providers ([name] NVARCHAR(100), [guid] NVARCHAR(100) NULL, [description] NVARCHAR(100) NULL);
INSERT INTO #providers EXEC sys.sp_enum_oledb_providers;
SELECT [name] FROM #providers;
```